Am I understanding Ulalek, Fused Atrocity?
Ulalek, Fused Atrocity says:

Whenever you cast an Eldrazi spell, you may pay {C}{C}. If you do,
copy all spells you control, then copy all other activated and
triggered abilities you control. You may choose new targets for the
copies. (Mana abilities can’t be copied.)

If it triggers, and I copy the trigger with something like Illusionist's Bracers, then the resolution of the copied trigger should itself create a copy of the original trigger.
Does this mean that I can continue to chain triggers and copied triggers for as many times as I can afford to pay {C}{C}?

Illusionists Bracers copies activated abilities, not triggered abilities. I'd suggest using Strionic Resonator as an example instead.

@murgatroid99 Echoes of Eternity is probably the best for a drazi deck, followed by Roaming Throne

The point was not to suggest a card that was strategically valuable for this deck, just a card that was an example of an effect that copies triggered abilities.

Yes, if you can get two copies of Ulalek's trigger on the stack at once, you can chain it together to copy each other spell and ability on the stack as many times as you can pay {C}{C}.
The key is that when the copy of Ulalek's trigger that's on top of the stack resolves, the other copy of the ability is "another triggered ability", so it will be copied along with the other spells and abilities. Then that creates another situation where there are two copies of Ulalek's trigger on the stack, so that creates a loop.
